# Adjoint operator and random variable

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, lp-spaces, adjoint-operators, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathbb{D}$ a dense subset of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$.

I consider a linear map $D$ from $\mathbb{D}\subset L^2(\Omega)$ to $L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$ and I denote by $\delta$ his adjoint operator that is the one satisfying

$$
\langle D(F),u\rangle_{L^2(\Omega\times[0,T])} = \langle \delta(u) , F\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$

Now I consider the linear map $\phi$ that associated to each $F\in\mathbb{D}$ $\phi(F) = \mathbb{E}[\langle D(F),u\rangle_{L^2([0,T])}]$, for $u\in L^2(\Omega\times[0,T])$.

First I extend $\phi$ by uniform continuity on the whole space.

Then by the Riesz representation theorem I know that there exists a unique $Z\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $\phi(F)=\mathbb{E}(ZF)$

I would like to prove the adjoint operator $\delta$ of the linear map $D$.

My idea is the following : define $\delta$ the adjoint operator by $\delta(u)=Z$ for each $F\in\mathbb{D}$, the map is well defined by the uniqueness of the Riesz representation theorem.

Does this seem correct please ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Could you please specify exactly what the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_{L^2(\Omega \times [0,T]}$ is?  And when you say "$\phi(F) = \mathbb{E}[\langle D(F),u\rangle_{L^2([0,T])}],$ you mean you're defining separate functions $\phi_u(F)$ for each $u \in L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$, right?

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! For the second point yes for each $u$ we defined a function $\phi_u$ ! For the first point it’s a good remark since I have no try to take a particular inner product.. I should think about that to be more cautious. But naturally what comes in mind is something like this $\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{T} x(s)y(s)ds]$

Comment: In that case, $\delta(u) = Z = Z_u$ seems like a reasonable guess.  There might be some work to show it is indeed bounded and linear, but hopefully it isn't too bad.

Comment: @user6247850 Yes this is exactly this you are right ! Thank you a lot !